# Expected constant expression

Tags: c, arrays

We have a snippet of C codes as below. Any solution cause all of it have been declared and initialize

```
void fillProcess(void *unused, Uint8 *stream, int len)
{
    Uint8 *waveptr;
    int waveleft=0;

    waveptr = wave.sound + wave.soundpos;
    waveleft = wave.soundlen - wave.soundpos;
    while ( waveleft <= len ) {
    /* Process samples */
    Uint8 process_buf[waveleft];
    SDL_memcpy(process_buf, waveptr, waveleft);
    /* do processing here, e.g. */
    /* processing the audio samples in process_buf[*] */
    // play the processed audio samples
    SDL_memcpy(stream, process_buf, waveleft);
    stream += waveleft;
    len -= waveleft;
    // ready to repeat play the audio
    waveptr = wave.sound;
    waveleft = wave.soundlen;
    wave.soundpos = 0;
    }
}
```

Getting 3 errors as below

```
Error   1   error C2057: expected constant expression   
Error   2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0    
Error   3   error C2133: 'process_buf' : unknown size
```

Comment: Errors have line numbers.  What line does each error occur on?

Comment: What compiler are you using? VLAs are just an extension of GCC

Comment: We are using visual studio and its pointing to Uint8 process_buf[waveleft];

Comment: You cant create C-array with a variable which value is not constant. So you need `const int waveleft = 1338; Uint8 process_buf[waveleft];`. I think thats all you need to fix.

Comment: What it is that you don't understand about each of them (in particular, the first one)? You can't allocate an array of size waveleft if waveleft is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Sp daniel how to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Abelenky it supppose to read raw audio bit and process it that is the actually function of it linking to SDL library callback

Comment: @Rookie You are **wrong**. Even with `const int waveleft;`, `Uint8 process_buf[waveleft];` is still VLA. In C, `const` variable is not a constant expression. This is one of the differences between C and C++.

Comment: Sorry guys I am very new to these term but learning good for me

Comment: @user2711681 VLS is short for variable length array, new in C99.

Answer (score 5):

```
Uint8 process_buf[waveleft];
```

This line uses variable length array, which is introduced in C99. But according to your error code, you are using Visual Studio, which doesn't support C99 yet.

Assuming that the compiler is still Visual Studio, you can allocate `process_buf` dynamically.

Comment: What is c99 represents here?

Comment: @user2711681 It's the informal name for  ISO/IEC 9899:1999, an ISO C standard that is passed in 1999. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99 for detail. What you are currently using is called C89/C90.

Comment: @user2711681 Google is your friend.

Comment: @user2711681: It represents a version *x*, supporting features which you don't have access to because your compiler doesn't support version *x*. For all intents and purposes, you can treat this as "Will Not Work For Me".

Comment: @Friends what is best work around can I put a static value here ?

Comment: @user2711681 No, static variable isn't helpful here. Either use `malloc` or find a compiler that supports C99.

Comment: @YuHao any sample on how to do malloc here sorry kind of new to all this

Comment: @user2711681 See the other answer, he provides the code using `malloc`.

Comment: Yes I saw and got this error Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Uint8 *'

Answer (score 2):

Use malloc to allocate process_buf:

```
void fillProcess(void *unused, Uint8 *stream, int len)
{
Uint8 *waveptr;
int waveleft=0;

waveptr = wave.sound + wave.soundpos;
waveleft = wave.soundlen - wave.soundpos;
    while ( waveleft <= len ) {
    /* Process samples */
    //Uint8 process_buf[waveleft];  // <-- OLD CODE
    Uint8 *process_buf = (Uint8 *)malloc(waveleft * sizeof(Uint8)); // <-- NEW CODE
    if(process_buf == 0) {
        // do something here
    }
    SDL_memcpy(process_buf, waveptr, waveleft);
    /* do processing here, e.g. */
    /* processing the audio samples in process_buf[*] */
    // play the processed audio samples
    SDL_memcpy(stream, process_buf, waveleft);
    stream += waveleft;
    len -= waveleft;
    // ready to repeat play the audio
    waveptr = wave.sound;
    waveleft = wave.soundlen;
    wave.soundpos = 0;
    // don't forget this:
    free(process_buf);  // <-- NEW CODE
    }
}
```

If malloc fails and returns 0, you need to decide what to do. Probably terminate
the program. fprintf(stderr) and exit(1) for example.

Comment: I got this error Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Uint8 *'

Comment: Wow. You have an old compiler. Use this instead: Uint8 *process_buf = (Uint8 *)malloc(waveleft * sizeof(Uint8)); I edited the code above too.

Comment: More likely he's compiling this as C++.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, it's tagged C so I'm going with that. I don't use Windows but I guess the Windows C compiler is stuck in the dark ages.

Comment: @Friend I think windows compiler thinks as C++ I guess yes Charlie your solution works now.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: MSVC won't complain about converting from `void *` when compiled as C. It's an out-of-date C compiler, but it's not quite that bad.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths so what is the best solution in my case using visual studio and dont quite get when you say converting from void * when compiled as C

Comment: @user2711681 You must be compiling a C++ project then, instead of C. Use `Uint8* process_buf = new Uint8[waveleft];` and `delete[] process_buf;` instead of `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: @user2711681: Your best bet is to decide whether you want to write in C or in C++. If you want to write in C++, then what Chrono Kitsune said is best. The best advice is to just spend some more time actually learning C or C++, these are pretty basic and fundamental things we're talking about.

Comment: @Yes I just realised the file is saved as .cpp is that fine to run as c++ ?

Comment: @user2711681: MSVC will, by default, compile `.cpp` files as C++, yes, But if you're writing in C++, please don't claim in your question that you're writing in C, because you'll get a lot of bad answers and you'll waste a lot of people's time.

Comment: @Paul sorry for my confusion and mix up can MSCV compile pure C codes ?

Comment: @user2711681: Yes, but only to a 24 year old version of C.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I dont get you what do you mean by 24 old version of C ?

Comment: @user2711681: I don't get what you don't get by it.

Comment: The C language has evolved since it's conception in the 1970s. Microsoft, for whatever reason, has decided to not keep their compilers up to date. Thus, the 24 year old version reference. My understanding is that Microsoft is encouraging you to move to another platform. But, I could be wrong about that.

Comment: What platform does microsoft encourage? Does MCVS have an option to compile pure .c not .cpp files?

Comment: If you change the file name extension from .cpp to .c, you C compiler will probably interpret that as a C file. Given their recent releases, Microsoft appears to be encouraging technically inclined people to use linux, others MacOS. Hope this helps.